# How to get values from javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have one javascript object. I want values like `item_name`, `item_cost` etc. from the object. How should I get it ?

This is my javascript object:

```
data: Array(3)
        0: {Item_name: "bourban-biscuits", Item_cost: 15, Item_quantity: 1, Total_cost: 15, Time: "3/17/2019, 4:26:05 PM"}
        1: {Item_name: "dark fantasy", Item_cost: 5, Item_quantity: 1, Total_cost: 5, Time: "3/17/2019, 4:26:20 PM"}
        2: {Item_name: ""}
```

Comment: Do you want to get all `item_name` from the array of objects? Or just one of them?

Comment: I want all @wentjun

Comment: You don't have one object, you have an array of objects.
And a weird syntax... or is it just me?

Comment: @RhugvedaDesai Ok.. and what is your desired output? How would you want it to be like

Comment: i want it in array format [item_name:biscuits, item_cost:5 ] @wentjun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the array of only `Item_names`, you can use JavaScript's [Array.map(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) operator:

```
const allNames = data.map(item => item.Item_name}
```

You can try running this to get a better idea:

```js
const data = [{Item_name: "bourban-biscuits", Item_cost: 15, Item_quantity: 1, Total_cost: 15, Time: "3/17/2019, 4:26:05 PM"}, {Item_name: "dark fantasy", Item_cost: 5, Item_quantity: 1, Total_cost: 5, Time: "3/17/2019, 4:26:20 PM"}, {Item_name: ""}];

 const res = data.map(item => item.Item_name);

 console.log(res);
```

Comment: @RhugvedaDesai I don't really understand what do you want. Can you update the input, and expected output on your question?

Comment: And what exactly do you want from data[0]?

Comment: i want { Item_name: "bourban-biscuits", Item_cost: 15, Item_quantity: 1, Total_cost: 15, Time: "3/17/2019, 4:26:05 PM"}  @wentjun

Comment: Isn't that just data[0]? If you want to get that object, why not just use `data[0]`?

Comment: data[0] is undefined @wentjun

Comment: console.log("data is: ",data[0]);  and this is the output   data is:  undefined

Comment: Oh.. What.. Hmm.. how about `console.log(data)`? what is printed?

Comment: this is the output       data is:  {data: Array(3), errors: Array(1), meta: {…}}

Comment: Oh, so so `data` is nested. In that case, you try `console.log(data.data[0])`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`:

```
const names = array.map(({ Item_name }) => Item_name);
```